# Basic question about wave funtions: using the Born rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, observables, born-rule

I have a textbook giving an example of what the probability is of observing system $Ψ = a|A⟩ + b|B⟩$ in states $a|A⟩$ and $b|B⟩$.
I'm not sure I understand it fully. How do I use the Born rule to know the probability of observing system $Ψ = a|A⟩ + b|B⟩ + c|C⟩$ in the state $c|C⟩$?
Could someone please give a rundown of the steps?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would want to calculate the probability of observing $\vert \Psi\rangle$ in the *normalized* state $\vert C\rangle$ (without the prefactor $c$).

1. Form the bra $\langle C\vert$.
2. Compute the overlap $\langle C\vert \Psi\rangle$:
   \begin{align}
   \langle C\vert \Psi\rangle=&a \langle C\vert A\rangle +b \langle C\vert B+ c\langle C\vert C\rangle\, ,\\
   &= c + a \langle C\vert A\rangle +b \langle C\vert B\rangle\, ,
   \end{align}
   where $\langle C\vert C \rangle =1 $ has been used.
3. Compute the modulus square of this (generally complex) number:
   $$
   P(\vert C\rangle) = 
   \vert c + a \langle C\vert A\rangle +b \langle C\vert B\rangle \vert^2
   = (c + a \langle C\vert A\rangle +b \langle C\vert B\rangle)^*
   (c + a \langle C\vert A\rangle +b \langle C\vert B\rangle)
   $$